# Im trying to Increase and Decrease the size of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator

Im trying to do my homeworks and its basically this. First I try to double the size of my array (from 5 to 10) then I try to decrease the size of it by Only one element.

This is what Ive done.

```
int size = 5;
int theKingOfKeepingSizes = size;
string *arr = new string[size];

size = size + 5;

string *arr2 = new string[size];


for (int i = 0; i < theKingOfKeepingSizes; i++)
{
    arr2[i] = arr[i];
}

delete[] arr;

arr = arr2;

int newsize = size - 1;
string *arr3 = new string[newsize];

for (int i = 0; i < newsize; i++)
{
    arr3[i] = arr2[i];
}

delete[] arr2;

arr2 = arr3;
```

Before you tell me `vector` can be used, I know. Im just following instructions. Am I doing it right though? If Im not, what can I improve, and. If Im doing it right, how can I put it to test? with names maybe? Im unsure on how to do that.

Thank you!

The instructions are :

1. Declare a pointer to a string-objekt.
2. Create an array of 5 element (here we assume that values are put in elements of the array)
3. Create an array double the size of the first one and use a help-pointer on it
4. Copy from the old and to the new array (with for-loop)
5. delete the old array.
6. Move the main pointer to the new array.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this code belongs on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Barry: SO is fine for code with known problems, and he knows what his problem is -- no tests.

Comment: Im  with @BenVoigt on this one.

Comment: @TarikNeaj Regarding "just following instructions" - I cannot know whether you do it right if I don't see your instructions. Some things in your code are not good; they may be OK though, if they don't contradict the instructions. To let people answer that part, please post the instructions.

Comment: @anatolyg I just did, thank you :)

Comment: The code looks correct to me, although maybe you don't need so many pointers (e.g. `arr` is dangling after the line `delete[] arr2;` because `arr` and `arr2` were both pointing to the same 10-element array at that point).

Answer (score 1):

explaining [Andy's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28139117/509868) just below: (I can't comment because i don't have enough reputation)

```
int main() 
{
    int size = 5;
    int size_2 = size;

    string *a_pt = new string [size]; //Intial size of 5.
```

This line declares a pointer to a string object. The `*` before `*a_pt` makes this a pointer; if it was a normal variable it would simply be `a_pt`.  It also creates an array of size 5, because it uses the variable `size` inside of the [ ] square brackets.

```
    cout<<size<<endl;
```

This line is used to debug. `cout` means console output. and `endl` means end of line. Anything between these two will be printed out in the console window. Here, `size` will be printed out, so you should see the number 5 in the console window.

For `cout` to work, you must write `#include <iostream>` at the top of the file, before `int main()`

```
    for (int i = 0; i <size_2; i++)
    {
        a_pt[i] = "Aa";
```

This line is filling the array with "Aa" in each element so `a_pt = [Aa, Aa, Aa, Aa, Aa]`

```
        cout<<a_pt[i]<<" ";  //Proveing size of 5
```

This line prints out each element of `a_pt` , so "Aa" should be printed out 5 times.

```
    }

    for (int o = 0; o <size_2; o++)
    { size+=1; } //Increasing size to 10.

    size_2 = size;
```

This part confuses me, instead of this you could write `size_2 = size*2;`

```
    cout<<endl<<size<<endl;

    for (int g = 0; g < size_2; g++)
    { 
        a_pt[g] = "Bb";
        cout<<a_pt[g]<<" ";     //Proving size of 10
    }
```

Just like the other `for` loop, this changes every element to "Bb", and then prints out each element. You should see "Bb" printed out 10 times now.
    }

Comment: You're the best around, Nothings gonna ever keep you down! Also thank you, I understand it good now :)

Answer (score -1):

looks alright to me! Though, if your homework is asking you to double the size it would be better to write :  "size = size*2"

the line "arr = arr2" also serves no purpose as you have already deleted the variable arr :)

Comment: By "arr = arr2" Im trying to (please bear with me Im translating from swedish) Move the main-pointer to the new array. Isint that what it does?

Comment: No, its not :) Im not sure you understand pointers, a _pointer_ is a variable that holds a memory address,  rather than a _normal variable_ which you have to get the memory address and then fetch the value.  <br/> I dont fully understand what you mean by "Move the main-pointer to the new array" , you do not need to move anything to a new array, the program will automatically go on to the new array when you start using `arr2` instead of `arr`

Comment: `arr` is a pointer, the line `arr = arr2;` makes the pointer `arr` point at the same memory block that `arr2` is pointing at.

Comment: Pointers are normal variables. It's just that the data they are holding represents an address (as opposed to, say, a string or a number).